# Suggestions for ways to find cheap accommodation in Turkey?

Tags: budget, accommodation, turkey, istanbul

We're a couple and we'll land in Istanbul on the night of the 10th of August for five days. We'd like to find cheap accommodation (possibly around €30, meaning €15 each) either in the city or in a nice village on the beach nearby. Since it's quite hot in August we'd prefer a place with air-conditioning or big windows in a green and windy area.

Comment: If your staying out of the city in budget accommodation take note to see if the water is solar heated, a big black barrel on the roof is a good give away. If this is the case shower in the evening rather than the morning or you will have an ice cold shower.

Comment: would you be happy with hostels? Some do have private rooms, if you're not partial to dorms.

Comment: As an alternative try bewelcome.org

Answer (score 5):

30 euros is possible, but you'll have to search for it. Air conditioning and big windows are a bit specific, which means you'll simply have to search longer.

Try http://www.hotelscombined.com/ for getting, often, the best rates on hotels.

Try http://www.airbnb.com/ if you're ok with staying in someone spare bedroom, or garden bungalow.

Typically, the latter will give you much better value for money, particularly if you're ok with not staying in the tourist center of Istanbul (which is Sultanahmet).

Comment: Sultanahmet is great for visiting the historic city. If you want to enjoy modern Istanbul and its nightlife, Taksim is worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking on airbnb.com?
here you have a few options on your dates:
[https://www.airbnb.com/s/Istanbul--Turkey?checkin=08%2F10%2F2014&checkout=08%2F15%2F2014&guests=2&price_max=30](https://www.airbnb.com/s/Istanbul--Turkey?checkin=08/10/2014&checkout=08/15/2014&guests=2&price_max=30)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out accommodation options on [cozycozy.com](https://www.cozycozy.com/us), here you can compare options from Airbnb, VRBO, etc and filter for the cheapest ones as you search.

Comment: Are you affiliated with that site?